# How to modify software serial to give me more interrupts (Mega)?

Tags: arduino, motion, android-gps

I have an Arduino Mega which I'm using with the [Ultimate GPS Logger shield](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-ultimate-gps-logger-shield/overview) (by Adafruit) and the [9-axis motion shield](https://coolcomponents.co.uk/products/9-axes-motion-shield?gclid=Cj0KCQiA0vnQBRDmARIsAEL0M1mzHPbA3AKjlxQBrQxpR5et5p38-wggjg4Ogdt7MKMpXmHDfCS4-uAaAnehEALw_wcB) (by Arduino)

I currently need 4 interrupts to act as wheel speed sensors (tachometers). However, currently software serial seems to use up all of these, and I'm only left with the interrupt from pin 2 (INT.0) that's currently working. Is there a way I can modify software serial to allow me to use more of the interrupts on the board?

Currently the Mega is using jumper cables like so to allow for compatibility (this is because the GPS shield isn't designed to fully work with the Arduino Mega).

```
//GPS 8  RX --> MEGA 18 TX1
//GPS 7  TX --> MEGA 29 0RX1
//GPS 13 CLK--> MEGA 52 SCK
//GPS 12 DI --> MEGA 51 MOSI
//GPS 11 DO --> MEGA 50 MISO
```

The 9-axis motion sensor and GPS offer to use interrupts but I don't want to use these unless they are strictly necessary. I initially tried using the pinchangeint library, however this does not work with the SoftwareSerial library!

My code is below:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Adafruit_GPS.h>
#include <SD.h>
#include <avr/sleep.h>
#include "NAxisMotion.h"
//Contains the bridge code between the API and the Arduino Environment (Accelerometer)
#include <Wire.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

//APPS definitions
#define APPSpin A0
double APPSvalue;

// Wheel speed definitions
#define FLpin  2 //WORKING
#define FRpin  21 //INT.1 (3) Does not work

volatile byte FLtooth;
volatile byte FRtooth;
double FLrpm;
double FRrpm;
unsigned long FLtime;
unsigned long FRtime;

// Accelerometer definitions
NAxisMotion mySensor; //Object that for the sensor
uint8_t range = 3; // 0 = 2G, 1 = 4G, 2 = 8G, 3 = 16G
uint8_t bandwidth = 3; // 0 - 7 = 7.81Hz x 2^bandwidth
uint8_t powerMode = 0; // 0 - 5 = Norm, Suspend, Low Power 1, Standby, Low Power 2, Deep Suspend
bool updateSensorData = true;
//Flag to update the sensor data. Default is true to perform the first read before the first stream

// Connect to the GPS on the hardware port     
#define GPSSerial Serial1
Adafruit_GPS GPS(&GPSSerial);

// Set GPSECHO to 'false' to turn off echoing the GPS data to the Serial console
// Set to 'true' if you want to debug and listen to the raw GPS sentences
#define GPSECHO true

// This keeps track of whether we're using the interrupt off by default!
boolean usingInterrupt = false;
void useInterrupt(boolean);

// Set Adafruit SD Card pin
#define chipSelect 10

File logfile;
uint32_t timer = millis();

void setup() {
  //SD Setup
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(chipSelect, OUTPUT);
  SD.begin(chipSelect, 11, 12, 13);

  //GPS Setup
  GPSSerial.begin(9600);
  // 9600 NMEA is the default baud rate for Adafruit MTK GPS's- some use 4800
  GPS.sendCommand(PMTK_SET_NMEA_OUTPUT_RMCONLY); //RMC (recommended minimum)
  GPS.sendCommand(PMTK_SET_NMEA_UPDATE_10HZ); // Set 1 Hz update rate (1Hz is suggested max), NOTE: This is the speed of the echo!
  GPS.sendCommand(PMTK_API_SET_FIX_CTL_5HZ); //Position fix update rate command
  GPS.sendCommand(PGCMD_ANTENNA); // Request updates on antenna status
  useInterrupt(true); //timer0 interrupt go off every 1ms and read GPS data

  char filename[15];
  strcpy(filename, "1.5_LOG00.csv");
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    filename[6] = '0' + i/10;
    filename[7] = '0' + i%10;
    if (! SD.exists(filename)) {
      break;
    }
  }
  logfile = SD.open(filename, FILE_WRITE);

  //APPS Setup
  APPSvalue = 0.00;

  //Wheel Speed Setup
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(FLpin), FLdetect, RISING);
  //Initialize the intterrupt pin
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(FRpin), FRdetect, RISING);
  FLtooth = 0;
  FRtooth = 0;
  FLrpm = 0.00;
  FRrpm = 0.00;
  FLtime = 0;
  FRtime = 0; 

  //Accelerometer Setup
  I2C.begin();
  //Initialize I2C communication to the let the library communicate with the sensor. 
  mySensor.initSensor();
  //The I2C Address can be changed here inside this function in the library
  mySensor.setOperationMode(OPERATION_MODE_NDOF);
  //Can be configured to other operation modes as desired
  mySensor.setPowerMode(0); //Normal = 0, Low Power = 1, Suspend = 2
  mySensor.setUpdateMode(MANUAL);
  //The default is AUTO. Changing to manual requires calling the relevant update functions prior to calling the read functions, setting to MANUAL requires lesser reads to the sensor
  mySensor.updateAccelConfig();
  updateSensorData = true;

  // Setup settings
  logfile.print("Accelerometer Range");
  logfile.print(", ");
  logfile.print(mySensor.readAccelRange());
  logfile.print(", ");
  logfile.println("2^(1+range)");
  logfile.print("Accelerometer Bandwidth");
  logfile.print(", ");
  logfile.print(mySensor.readAccelBandwidth());
  logfile.print(", ");
  logfile.println("7.81Hz x 2^bandwidth");
  logfile.print("Accelerometer Power Mode");
  logfile.print(", ");
  logfile.print(mySensor.readAccelPowerMode());
  logfile.print(", ");
  logfile.println("0 - 5 = Norm - Suspend - Low Power 1 - Standby - Low Power 2 - Deep Suspend");
  logfile.println();

  // Setup headings
  logfile.print("GPS Fix");
  logfile.print(", ");
  logfile.print("Time (5Hz)");
  logfile.print(", ");
  logfile.print("Date");
  logfile.print(", ");
  logfile.print("Latitude (5Hz)");
  logfile.print(", ");
  logfile.print("Longitude (5Hz)");
  logfile.print(", ");
  logfile.print("Throttle / %");
  logfile.print(", ");
  logfile.print("FL RPM");
  logfile.print(", ");
  logfile.print("FR RPM");
  logfile.print(", ");
  logfile.print("Acc X / m/s2");
  logfile.print(", ");
  logfile.print("Acc Y / m/s2");
  logfile.print(", ");
  logfile.print("Acc Z / m/s2");
  logfile.print(", ");
  logfile.print("LinAcc X / m/s2");
  logfile.print(", ");
  logfile.print("LinAcc Y / m/s2");
  logfile.print(", ");
  logfile.print("LinAcc Z / m/s2");
  logfile.print(", ");
  logfile.print("GracAcc X / m/s2");
  logfile.print(", ");
  logfile.print("GracAcc Y / m/s2");
  logfile.print(", ");
  logfile.print("GracAcc Z / m/s2");
  logfile.print(", ");
  logfile.print("Heading / deg");
  logfile.print(", ");
  logfile.print("Roll / deg");
  logfile.print(", ");
  logfile.print("Pitch / deg");
  logfile.print(", ");
  logfile.print("Acc Calibration");
  logfile.print(", ");
  logfile.print("Gyroscope Calibration");
  logfile.print(", ");
  logfile.print("System Calibration");
  logfile.println();
  logfile.flush(); //Waits for the transmission of outgoing serial data to complete
}

// Interrupt is called once a millisecond, looks for any new GPS data, and stores it
SIGNAL(TIMER0_COMPA_vect) {
  char c = GPS.read();
}

void useInterrupt(boolean v) {
  if (v) {
    // Timer0 is already used for millis() - we'll just interrupt somewhere
    // in the middle and call the "Compare A" function above
    OCR0A = 0xAF;
    TIMSK0 |= _BV(OCIE0A);
    usingInterrupt = true;
  } else {
    // do not call the interrupt function COMPA anymore
    TIMSK0 &= ~_BV(OCIE0A);
    usingInterrupt = false;
  }
}

double convertDegMinToDecDeg (float degMin) {
  // converts lat/long from Adafruit degree-minute (DDM) format to decimal-degrees (DD)
  double min = 0.0;
  double decDeg = 0.0;

  //get the minutes, fmod() requires double
  min = fmod((double)degMin, 100.0);

  //rebuild coordinates in decimal degrees
  degMin = (int) ( degMin / 100 );
  decDeg = degMin + ( min / 60 );
  return decDeg;
}

void FLdetect() {
  //This function is called whenever a magnet/interrupt is detected by the Arduino
   FLtooth++;
   Serial.print("teeth: ");
   Serial.println(FLtooth);
 }

void FRdetect() {
  //This function is called whenever a magnet/interrupt is detected by the Arduino
  FRtooth++;
  Serial.print("teeth: ");
  Serial.println(FLtooth);
}

void FL_RPM() {
  //Measure RPM
  if (FLtooth >= 5) {
    FLrpm = (10.0*1000/((millis() - FLtime)));
    FLtime = millis();
    FLtooth = 0;
    return FLrpm;
  }
}

void FR_RPM() {
  //Measure RPM
  if (FRtooth >= 5) {
    FRrpm = (10.0*1000/((millis() - FRtime)));
    FRtime = millis();
    FRtooth = 0;
    return FRrpm;
  }
}

void loop() {
  if (!usingInterrupt) {
    // read data from the GPS in the 'main loop'
    char c = GPS.read();
  }
  // if a sentence is received, we can check the checksum, parse it...
  if (GPS.newNMEAreceived()) {
    // a tricky thing here is if we print the NMEA sentence, or data
    // we end up not listening and catching other sentences!
    // so be very wary if using OUTPUT_ALLDATA and trytng to print out data
    Serial.println(GPS.lastNMEA());
    // this also sets the newNMEAreceived() flag to false
    if (!GPS.parse(GPS.lastNMEA()))
      // this also sets the newNMEAreceived() flag to false
      return;
      // we can fail to parse a sentence in which case we should just wait for another
  }

  if (updateSensorData) {
    //Keep the updating of data as a separate task
    mySensor.updateAccel(); //Update the Accelerometer data
    mySensor.updateLinearAccel(); //Update the Linear Acceleration data
    mySensor.updateGravAccel(); //Update the Gravity Acceleration data
    mySensor.updateEuler(); //Update the Euler data into the structure of the object
    mySensor.updateCalibStatus(); //Update the Calibration Status
    updateSensorData = false;
  }

  FL_RPM();
  FR_RPM();
  APPSvalue = map(analogRead(APPSpin), 552, 710, 0, 100) ;

  // if millis() or timer wraps around, we'll just reset it
  if (timer > millis()) timer = millis();

  // approximately every 2 seconds or so, print out the current stats
  if (millis() - timer > 100) {
    timer = millis(); // reset the timer
    logfile.print((int)GPS.fix);    
    logfile.print(", ");
    logfile.print(GPS.hour, DEC); logfile.print(':');
    logfile.print(GPS.minute, DEC); logfile.print(':');
    logfile.print(GPS.seconds, DEC); logfile.print('.');
    logfile.print(GPS.milliseconds);
    logfile.print(", ");
    logfile.print(GPS.day, DEC); logfile.print('/');
    logfile.print(GPS.month, DEC); logfile.print("/20");
    logfile.print(GPS.year, DEC);
    logfile.print(", ");      
    logfile.print(convertDegMinToDecDeg(GPS.latitude),6);
    logfile.print(", ");
    logfile.print(-convertDegMinToDecDeg(GPS.longitude),6);
    logfile.print(", ");      
    logfile.print(APPSvalue,2);
    logfile.print(", ");
    logfile.print(FLrpm,2);
    logfile.print(", ");
    logfile.print(FRrpm,2);
    logfile.print(", ");
    logfile.print(mySensor.readAccelX()); //Accelerometer X-Axis data
    logfile.print(", ");
    logfile.print(mySensor.readAccelY()); //Accelerometer Y-Axis data
    logfile.print(", ");
    logfile.print(mySensor.readAccelZ()); //Accelerometer Z-Axis data
    logfile.print(", ");
    logfile.print(mySensor.readLinearAccelX()); //Linear Acceleration X-Axis data  
    logfile.print(", ");
    logfile.print(mySensor.readLinearAccelY()); //Linear Acceleration Y-Axis data  
    logfile.print(", ");
    logfile.print(mySensor.readLinearAccelZ()); //Linear Acceleration Z-Axis data  
    logfile.print(", ");
    logfile.print(mySensor.readGravAccelX()); //Gravity Acceleration X-Axis data
    logfile.print(", ");
    logfile.print(mySensor.readGravAccelY()); //Gravity Acceleration Y-Axis data
    logfile.print(", ");
    logfile.print(mySensor.readGravAccelZ()); //Gravity Acceleration Z-Axis data
    logfile.print(", ");
    logfile.print(mySensor.readEulerHeading()); //Heading data
    logfile.print(", ");
    logfile.print(mySensor.readEulerRoll()); //Roll data
    logfile.print(", ");
    logfile.print(mySensor.readEulerPitch()); //Pitch data
    logfile.print(", ");
    logfile.print(mySensor.readAccelCalibStatus()); //Accelerometer Calibration Status (0 - 3)
    logfile.print(", ");
    logfile.print(mySensor.readGyroCalibStatus()); //Gyroscope Calibration Status (0 - 3)
    logfile.print(", ");
    logfile.print(mySensor.readSystemCalibStatus()); //System Calibration Status (0 - 3)
    logfile.println();
    logfile.flush();
    updateSensorData = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to use software serial in the first place? You have 4 hardware serial interfaces on a Mega.

Comment: Not only that, but you declare SoftwareSerial.h but don't use it...